# MySQL ADDDATE, DATE_FORMAT and CONCAT_WS

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I am building the following Query but am having syntax problems:

```
SELECT FORMAT(yrs_served * 365, 0) AS days_served,
ADDDATE(date_comm, INTERVAL days_served DAY(DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS('-', yr_comm, mth_comm, day_comm), %Y-%m-%d) AS date_comm) AS left_office
FROM prime_minister JOIN ministry
;
```

As can been seen, I am first trying to CONCAT_WS three values into a date, then format it as a date with DATE_FORMAT, so that I can then use ADDDATE to add a number of days to this date.

Please advise where I am going wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use `ALIAS` on the same level it has been define.

```
SELECT   FORMAT(yrs_served * 365, 0) AS days_served,
         ADDDATE(CONCAT_WS('-', yr_comm, mth_comm, day_comm), INTERVAL (yrs_served * 365) DAY) AS left_office
FROM     prime_minister JOIN ministry.....
```

if you wan't to use it, you just wrap it in a subquery, eg

```
SELECT  days_served,
        ADDDATE(date_comm, INTERVAL days_served DAY) AS left_office
FROM
(
    SELECT  FORMAT(yrs_served * 365, 0) AS days_served,
            CONCAT_WS('-', yr_comm, mth_comm, day_comm) as date_comm
    FROM     prime_minister JOIN ministry.....
) s
```

- [ADDDATE (*same with `DATE_ADD`*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I knew I was close, but just the syntax / structure was evading me as I am new to SQL. Cheers!